# Find the index of the element with maximum absolute deviation

Tags: python, programming-challenge, complexity

I just completed a Codility test. The question presented was pretty simple but I may have over thought it.

Question:

> Find the element which has the highest absolute deviation from the mean. E.g. `Array = [1,1,-1,1]`.The average is 0.5, so the absolute deviation for each element in the array is `[0.5,0.5,1.5,0.5]` (note that the `-1.5` goes to `1.5` after taking the absolute values of each deviation value) and thus the index with the max absolute deviation is `2` (the index starts from `0`).

My code was:

```
def solution(A):
    if len(A) > 0:
        average = sum(A)*1.0/len(A)
        max_avg = 0
        pos = 0            
        for i in range(len(A)):
            if abs(A[i] - average) > max_avg:
                max_avg = abs(A[i] - average)
                pos = i
        return pos
    else:
        return -1
```

If there's a tie between the max deviation elements i.e. two or more indexes have the same absolute deviation then either of them can be given. The required time-complexity is \$O(N)\$ and space-complexity is \$O(1)\$. In theory, this problem should be really easy but this was my first technical test and I might have overlooked something. Did I possibly miss anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that in Python 3, you don't need `* 1.0` to get floating-point division.  On the other hand, in Python 2, `range(len(A))` would use O(N) space.

I recommend three changes:

- Put the special case first, to reduce the separation between `return -1` and the reason for returning -1.
- Rename `max_avg` → `max_deviation`.
- Use `enumerate()` to iterate over the array.

The revised solution would be:

```
def solution(A):
    if not A:
        return -1
    average = sum(A) * 1.0 / len(A)
    max_deviation = 0
    pos = 0
    for i, a in enumerate(A):
        if abs(a - average) > max_deviation:
            max_deviation = abs(a - average)
            pos = i
    return pos
```

Comment: Wow, did not know that `range(len(A))` uses space in Python2 but it does make sense now that I think about it. Unusually enough I did a demo Codility test before my actual test and I didn't have any memory flags even though I used `range(...)` as my iterable. I'll be sure to use `enumerate()` from now on in Python2.7. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: You can use `xrange` in python 2.x

Comment: @Caridorc using `xrange()` seems like a good substitute for `range()`. It also seems to be faster than `range()` and `enumerate()` in Python2.

Answer (score 3):

@200_success already covered most of the points I had in my mind, apart from their suggestion one thing I would like to suggest you is that you can also use the built-in function [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#max) with a custom key function for this.

The key function used with `max` is passed the item from the iterable, so we surely cannot use the sequence we are passing to our function because we need to find out the index. So, we can use `range()`(or `xrange()` in  Python 2). Here I have defined the `key_func` inside of our function so that it can access `average` and `seq`.

```
def solution(seq):
    if not seq:
        return -1
    length = len(seq)
    average = sum(seq)/length

    def key_func(ind):
        val = seq[ind]
        return abs(average - val)

    pos = max(range(length), key=key_func)
    return pos
```

We can also move the `key_func` outside but in that case we need to make sure it knows about `seq` and `average`, to do that change `key_func` to accept three arguments. But as `max` can pass only one argument(i.e index) we need to specify the other two somehow, that's where [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html#functools.partial) comes in:

```
from functools import partial


def find_abs(seq, average, ind):
    val = seq[ind]
    return abs(average - val)


def solution_range(seq):
    if not seq:
        return -1
    length = len(seq)
    average = sum(seq)/length
    # Create a new function around our key function using functools.partial
    # with seq and average.   
    key_func = partial(find_abs, seq, average)
    pos = max(range(length), key=key_func)
    return pos
```

Another option is to use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#enumerate) with `max` instead of `range`(or `xrange()`), this will allow us to return both the index as well as corresponding item and now we need to pass only `average` to `functools.partial`:

```
def find_abs(average, index_val):
    index, val = index_val
    return abs(average - val)


def solution_enumerate(seq):
    if not seq:
        return -1
    length = len(seq)
    average = sum(seq)/length
    key_func = partial(find_abs, average)
    pos, item = max(enumerate(seq), key=key_func)
    return pos
```

---

## For Python 2:

- To make sure the above solution work in Python 2 both fast and correctly use [`xrange()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) instead of [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) and replace `sum(seq)/length` with `sum(seq)/float(length)`.
- Python 2 also allowed argument tuple parameter unpacking but that is [not available in Python 3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/) anymore, with the `enumerate` version we could have used it like this:

```
def find_abs(average, (index, val)):
    return abs(average - val)
```

Answer (score 1):

`if len(A) > 0` should be `if A`.

You should name thing better; `A` is both the wrong case and far too short.

You should short-ciruit the error case. In fact, you should throw an error.

If you're on Python 3, you don't need to `* 1.0`, and if not you should just `from __future__ import division` to get Python 3's behaviour. If you really don't want to, you should still use a `float` call instead.

You should use `statistics.mean` to find the mean. If you're on Python 2, this isn't an option without a backport. This will throw a good error for you, so you could remove that check.

You should use `for i, val in enumerate(items)` over `for i in range(len(items)): val = item`.

Since you only want the index, you can just do

```
deviations = (abs(item - average) for item in items)
```

and find the maximum of that. To get the index, just do

```
maxima, index = max((val, idx) for idx, val in enumerate(deviations))
```

Altogether:

```
import statistics

def solution(items):
    average = statistics.mean(items)

    deviations = (abs(item - average) for item in items)
    maxima, index = max((val, idx) for idx, val in enumerate(deviations))

    return index
```

Comment: the name `A` is required by the platform. Wouldn't `deviations = (abs(item - average) for item in items)` require O(N) space? Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @Black Nope, it's an iterator.